# is a NSMutableSet implemented like a linked list?

Tags: objective-c, linked-list, nsset

Since you can not access element of the NSMutableSet randomly, does this mean it is implemented like a linked list?

I.e. will it have faster insertion / deletion than a NSMutableArray?

Comment: This question follows... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422141/objective-c-what-structure-should-i-use-to-store-these-objects

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The source code is available, so you can have a look: [CFSet.c](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-550.42/CFSet.c) . (This is a Core Foundation counterpart to `NSSet`, but they are basically the same.) It's a hash table.

But you should also bear in mind that `NSArray` is, in fact, not implemented as an array. You can see the implementation here: [CFArray.c](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-550.42/CFArray.c). Maybe [this blog article](http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/archives/2005/12/23/array/) is easier to understand, although it's a bit dated (~5 years.)

Answer (score 2):

No. Lookup time will be faster because it will use hashes.

Answer (score 2):

I am no Objective-C progammer, but usually sets are implemented through hash-tables, which (if properly done) will yield O(1) for insert, delete and lookup.

Technically, hashes typically give you O(M), where M is the size of the key, but for a set you would simply use the id of the key object, which is constant, so you're back to O(1).

Answer (score 0):

Sets are normally implemented with balanced binary search trees (e.g. red-black trees, avl trees).

Comment: Hashtables give you O(1) for insert, delete and lookup. Trees need at least O(log(N)) for any of those. See my answer.

Comment: @back2dos: hashes are only used if you do not need ordering. Because of this restriction, there are HashMap and TreeMap in java, and map and unordered_map in C++. There are also TreeSet and HashSet in java.

Comment: Agreed, although by definition sets have "no particular order" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(computer_science)

Comment: Also, you can have ordered hashes by having a linked list and a hash of cells.